# Python. How to make the previously entered value in telegram appear in the line "Write a message"

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

Hello. Need help) There is a code:

```
def edit(message):
    num = int(message.text)
    num = num - 1
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, list[num])
```

The logic is simple. The person enters data. They are saved in the list under their own number. The person then enters a number to edit their entry. And is it possible to make his entry appear in the "enter message" line, and not receive individual SMS.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8M0o.png)
Thanks in advance)